# Evaluate double integral $\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{4-x^2} \frac{x\cos 3y}{4-y}dydx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I go about evaluating...

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{4-x^2} \frac{x\cos3y}{4-y}dydx$$

I don't really have any work to show, since I don't even know how to start this problem, but I'll offer my thought process to show you what I've thought about and we'll see where to go from there.

I can't think of any particular reason why circular, spherical or cylindrical substitutions would make sense here. For this reason, I feel like a different type of substitution would be necessary...but...what? I don't know what type of substitution would make this easier. I couldn't just say that $ u = 4-y $, because in the numerator, I already have that nasty $ \cos3y $ term.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @pizza I'm afraid I'm not seeing the trick, could you explain a bit more...?

Comment: @pizza I don't see how it becomes 0. After flipping the integration, I get $ \frac{sin(12)}{6} $

Comment: Future comment for those examining the question - this question does NOT have a duplicate, I mistakenly marked it as so. The answer is indeed, $ \frac{sin(12)}{6} $

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Polar Coordinates. Switching coordinates is frequently the best way to get things to work out.

Comment: From my standpoint, I couldn't imagine a more difficult substitution. Reversing the order does wonders.

Comment: Got me there =D.

Answer (score 0):

Note
$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{4-x^2} \frac{x\cos3y}{4-y}dydx
= \int_{0}^{4}\int^{\sqrt{4-y}}_0 \frac{x\cos3y}{4-y}dx dy= \frac12 \int_{0}^{4}\cos3y\ dy
$$